# Custom Upload function

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

How to get content of file in javascript only using [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) plugin. For example :

```
Dropzone.options.fbDropZone = {
    init: function () {
        alert(1);
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) { console.log(file); });

    // How to get content here 
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with placing code inside the `init` callback "addedfile" function?

Comment: is all explained in documentation: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration